# How to execute parameterized SQL query (using LIKE with @ variable)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-like

I want to do select query with input from user, what is the correct syntax of `LIKE` to use, where I should set `%` in the first line or second?

```
var areaName = "SELECT AOIId FROM dbo.AreaOFInterest WHERE AOIName LIKE @AOIName ";
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(areaName, @searching);
```

Comment: This is about your programming language, where you're trying to invoke this, not about sql.

Comment: I'm use asp.net mvc c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search for all names starting with the specified characters, specify `LIKE @AOIName + '%'`. For all name containing the string, specify `LIKE '%' @AOIName + '%'`.

You may also want to escape LIKE wildcards within the provided search string so that these are treated as literals:

```
var aoiNameParameterValue = AOIName.Replace("[", "[[]").Replace("%", "[%]").Replace("_", "[_]").Replace("^", "[^]");
```

Comment: Thanks but what you mean by replace?

Comment: I mean enclose wildcard characters within the search string in square brackets. I used the String.Replace method in my code example to do that.